# How I can match multiple dataframes with multiple IDs in R

Tags: r

I have the following DFs, as an example

```html
  

  df1<-read.table (text="  ID1  speed   ID2 Time    ID3 Income
    4   60  5   100 3   300
    3   80  2   90  7   400
    2   90  6   100 6   600

    ", header=TRUE)
```

```html
df2<-read.table (text="  ID Colour  CA  NA  DC  NO
2   Y   Y   N12 A   B-12
3   B   N   M18 B   B-17
6   R   Y   M20 E   B-22
4   P   N   M22 F   B-27
7   B   Y   M11 G   B-32
", header=TRUE)
```

```html
The expected outcome is

ID1 speed1  Colour1 CA1 NA1 DC1 NO1 ID2 Time    Colour2 CA2 NA2 DC2 NO2 ID3 Income  Colour3 CA3 NA3 DC3 NO3
4   60  P   N   M22 F   B-27    5   100 NA  xx  xx  xx  xx  3   300 xx  xx  xx  xx  xx
3   80  B   N   M18 B   B-17    2   90  Y   xx  xx  xx  xx  7   400 xx  xx  xx  xx  xx
2   90  Y   Y   N12 A   B-12    6   100 Y   xx  xx  xx  xx  6   600 xx  xx  xx  xx  xx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the input and expected, it seems that we need a join individually on the 'ID' columns from 'df1' with that of 'ID' on 'df2'.  Get the 'ID' column names ('nm1'), and the names of the 'df2' that are not found in 'df1'.  Loop over the sequence of ID columns, do a join and assign (`:=`) the values of 'nm2' columns by joining on the 'ID' with the corresponding 'ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3' from 'df1'

```
library(data.table)
df3 <- copy(df1)
nm1 <- grep("^ID\\d+$", names(df1), value = TRUE)
nm2 <- setdiff(setdiff(names(df2), names(df1)), "ID")
 
 setDT(df3)
 for(i in seq_along(nm1)) {
     
   df3[df2, paste0(nm2, i) := mget(nm2), on = setNames("ID", nm1[i])][]
 }
```

-output

```
df3
   ID1 speed ID2 Time ID3 Income Colour1 CA1 NA.1 DC1  NO1 Colour2  CA2 NA.2  DC2  NO2 Colour3 CA3 NA.3 DC3  NO3
1:   4    60   5  100   3    300       P   N  M22   F B-27    <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>       B   N  M18   B B-17
2:   3    80   2   90   7    400       B   N  M18   B B-17       Y    Y  N12    A B-12       B   Y  M11   G B-32
3:   2    90   6  100   6    600       Y   Y  N12   A B-12       R    Y  M20    E B-22       R   Y  M20   E B-22
```

---

or another option is reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer`, do a join with `left_join` and then reshape back to 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(readr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('ID'), values_to = 'ID') %>% 
   left_join(df2) %>%
   mutate(name = parse_number(name)) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = ID:NO, names_sep="") %>%
   select(-rn)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 21
  speed  Time Income   ID1   ID2   ID3 Colour1 Colour2 Colour3 CA1   CA2   CA3   NA.1  NA.2  NA.3  DC1   DC2   DC3   NO1   NO2   NO3  
  <int> <int>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1    60   100    300     4     5     3 P       <NA>    B       N     <NA>  N     M22   <NA>  M18   F     <NA>  B     B-27  <NA>  B-17 
2    80    90    400     3     2     7 B       Y       B       N     Y     Y     M18   N12   M11   B     A     G     B-17  B-12  B-32 
3    90   100    600     2     6     6 Y       R       R       Y     Y     Y     N12   M20   M20   A     E     E     B-12  B-22  B-22
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry does not help. For example, ID2, Time Colour should read NA, Y, Y and so on.

Comment: @user330 Is the expected output the full expected or just a part of the expected

Comment: Thanks, Yes, the full expected.

Comment: @user330 it is because of your description `I also need to get same data for ID2 and ID3 with different IDs.`

Comment: They use the IDs that are addressed in df2

Comment: My doubt is whether you are joining ID1, ID2, ID3, individually to ID in the other data

Comment: @user330 Can you please check the soluiton.  I updated with two solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's great indeed! I have upvoted your solutions.